# Figuring out partial fractions using Taylor series

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

> Suppose the factor $(x-a)$ in the denominator to be repeated $r$ times, so that,
> $$ \phi(x) = (x-a)^r \Phi(x)$$
> Let $$ x-a = y$$
> Then,
> $$ \frac{f(x)}{\phi(x)} = \frac{ f(a+y)}{y^r \Phi(a+y)}$$
> or expanding each function by any means in ascending powers of 'y'
> $$ \frac{ f(a+y)}{y^r \Phi(a+y)}= \frac{A_o + A_1 y + A_2 y^2...}{y^r ( B_o + B_1 y +b_2 y^2...)}$$
> Divide out thus:-
> $$ B_o + B_1 y + .. A_O + A_1 y + C_o + C_1 y + C_2 y^2... $$
> and let division continue until $y^r$ is a factor of the remainder. Let the remainder be $ y^r \chi (y)$
> Hence the fraction =$$ \frac{C_o}{y^r} + \frac{C_1}{y^r-1} ... + \frac{C_{r-1} }{y} + \frac{ \chi (y) }{ \phi(a+y)} =\frac{C_o}{(x-a)^r} + \frac{C_1}{(x-a)^{r-1}} ... + \frac{C_{r-1} }{(x-a)} + \frac{ \chi ((x-a)) }{ \phi(a+y)} $$
> -Differential Calculus for Beginners, Joseph Edwards

Ok, so I'm quite confused as to what he meant in the 'Divide out thus' step. What exactly is this new series he writes in the next line? Further after seeing this, I thought could we split reciprocal of functions with a 'nicely' convergent series using this technique?